# Comando não encontrado bash

Tags: linux, bash

Estou encontrado o seguinte erro ao executar esse script:

> linha 7: [1: comando não encontrado

```
#!/bin/bash


#$ for counter in $(seq 1 255); do curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/echo-json -d '[{"id": "123", "name": "oi"}]'; done
for counter in $(seq 1 600)
do
    if ["$counter" == 2]; then
        echo oi
        curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/echo-json -d '[{"id": "123", "name": '"$counter"'}]'
    fi
    curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/echo-json -d '[{"id": "123", "name":'"$counter"'}]'

sleep 1
done
```

Comment: 1) `sudo apt-get update` 2) `sudo apt-get install curl`

Comment: Eu ja tenho instalado, acho que o problema esta no if, pois o echo oi não ta aparecendo tbm

Comment: oi não teria que estar entre aspas?

Comment: botei e não adiantou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tudo certo?!

Tente executar o "if" exatamente da seguinte forma:

```
   if [ $counter == '2' ]; then
    echo "oi"
   fi
```

Fiz um teste daqui e funcionou. Segue:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços!